# Create an element modeled in SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I would like to create an **HTML element modeled on an SVG**.

I tried the following options:

`<object>`: The tag is working but is causing problems in the animation of the svg. (You can not move the item without generating bugs)

`<svg>`: The tag does not allow me to add other elements inside, which is forced me to do.

`background-image: url (path);` does not allow modeling but just to put the image of the svg in the background. The model does not apply and leaves the user activated "onclick" when he clicks on non-drawn edges.

There would be something that could make a  tag modeled on the SVG, so that the event "onclick" does not fire if we click on the "square" of the Div but on the round?

Here is a small diagram that summarizes the situation

[image]

Well in reality, as you will understand it is not a round model that I want to set up, it's a kind of tab menu, here is an overview:

[image]

I use JQUERYUI to handle tab moves, and the  tag causes bugs that make it impossible to use.

An imaginary code that could fulfill this function I would like it to exist

```
<div model="https://example.com/model.svg">
    <span>A untitled tab</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A link element in SVG document

If i understand you right you want a clickable svg tab?

```css
.menu-link polygon {
  fill: #222;
  stroke: #66e;
}

.menu-link:hover polygon {
  fill: #eee;
  stroke: #88f;
}
.menu-link:hover text {
  fill: #222;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
  <a class="menu-link" href="#">
    <polygon points=" 15,15 20,5 40,5 45,15 15,15"></polygon>
    <text x="20" y="12" fill="white" font-size="0.35em">Text here</text>
  </a>
  <a class="menu-link" href="#">
    <polygon fill="#222" stroke="pink" points=" 50,15 55,5 80,5 85,15 55,15"></polygon>
    <text x="56" y="12" fill="white" font-size="0.35em">Other text</text>
  </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, I'll check if it's not a problem with JqueryUI, like with the tag <object>

Comment: @Chr Let me spare you the effort: jquery and jqueryUI don't like svg. Its better to just use vanilla javascript to select svg elements.

Comment: I agree with you, I do not like that, but rather than recode all the functions ...